# What is the best approach for redirection of old pages in Jekyll and GitHub Pages?

Tags: redirect, github, jekyll, http-status-code-301, github-pages

I have blog on github pages - jekyll

What is the best way to solve url strategy migration?

I found the best practice in common is create htaccess like so

```
Redirect 301 /programovani/2010/04/git-co-to-je-a-co-s-tim/ /2010/04/05/git-co-to-je-a-co-s-tim.html
```

But it does not seems to work with Github. Another solution i found is create rake task, which will generate redirection pages. But since it's an html, it's not able to send `301` head, so SE crawlers will not recognize it as an redirection.

Comment: This worked for me: https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The best solution is to use both `<meta http-equiv="refresh"` and `<link rel="canonical" href=`

It works very well, Google Bot reindexed my entire website under new links without losing positions. Also the users are redirected to the new posts right away.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://konradpodgorski.com/blog/2013/10/21/how-i-migrated-my-blog-from-wordpress-to-octopress/">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://konradpodgorski.com/blog/2013/10/21/how-i-migrated-my-blog-from-wordpress-to-octopress/" />
```

Using `<meta http-equiv="refresh"` will redirect each visitor to the new post.
 As for Google Bot, it treats `<link rel="canonical" href=` as 301 redirect, the effect is that you get your pages reindexed and that is what you want.

I described whole process how I moved my blog from Wordpress to Octopress here.
http://konradpodgorski.com/blog/2013/10/21/how-i-migrated-my-blog-from-wordpress-to-octopress/#redirect-301-on-github-pages

Comment: When moving to GitHub pages, this worked for me: https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages. It looks like it does everything you mentioned.

Comment: Does the effect of using `canonical` imply that Google will reindex the pages from scratch, or does it transfer the ranking score to the new page? Can you clarify how this approach affects the page ranking?

Comment: Won't the `<meta http-equiv="refresh"` cause an infinite redirect loop? That is what I am getting, maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @ErikBerkun-Drevnig the content seen above is added on the "old" page and should point to the "new" page.  Done that way, there should not be an infinite loop.

Comment: If anyone is wondering: those two lines should be included in your `<head>` block.

Answer (score 24):

Have you tried the [Jekyll Alias Generator plugin](https://github.com/tsmango/jekyll_alias_generator)?

You put the alias urls in the YAML front matter of a post:

```
---
  layout: post
  title: "My Post With Aliases"
  alias: [/first-alias/index.html, /second-alias/index.html]
---
```

When a user visits one of the alias urls, they are redirected to the main url via a meta tag refresh:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/blog/my-post-with-aliases/" />
  </head>
</html>
```

See also [this blog post](http://rawsyntax.com/blog/blogging-on-jekyll-url-redirects/) on the subject.

Comment: GitHub Pages does not use plugins

Comment: @tekknolagi Perhaps I don't understand GitHub Pages. But if you are running jekyll, and just posting the static site to Github, then this would work, as the generated pages would include meta refreshes for the old urls?

Comment: that is correct, but GitHub won't run Jekyll with the plugins, just serve the compiled static site

Comment: I've ended up with something like this. I generate the redirection pages locally by Rake task and push them to Github as static pages

Comment: I followed this approach and it was pretty easy. I ran into two issues: 1) the plugin wouldn't run--I had to set `safe: false` in `_config.yml` 2) I was going to have to create over 400 alias entries. Instead of hand-crafting those, I automated it with a Python script: https://gist.github.com/smholloway/8726873

Answer (score 16):

**redirect-from plugin**

https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from#redirect-to

It is supported by GitHub and makes it easy:

_config.yml

```
gems:
  - jekyll-redirect-from
```

a.md

```
---
permalink: /a
redirect_to: 'http://example.com'
---
```

as explained at: https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/

Now:

```
firefox localhost:4000/a
```

will redirect you to `example.com`.

The plugin takes over whenever the `redirect_to` is defined by the page.

Tested on GitHub pages v64.

*Note*: this version has a serious recently fixed bug which wrongly reuses the default layout for the redirect: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from/pull/106

**Manual layout method**

If you don't feel like using https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from it's easy to implement it yourself:

a.md

```
---
layout: 'redirect'
permalink: /a
redir_to: 'http://example.com'
sitemap: false
---
```

`_layouts/redirect.html` based on [Redirect from an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411538/redirect-from-an-html-page) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Redirecting...</title>
  {% comment %}
    Don't use 'redirect_to' to avoid conflict
    with the page redirection plugin: if that is defined
    it takes over.
  {% endcomment %}
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ page.redir_to }}"/>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url={{ page.redir_to }}" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Redirecting...</h1>
  <a href="{{ page.redir_to }}">Click here if you are not redirected.<a>
  <script>location='{{ page.redir_to }}'</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Like this example, the `redirect-from` plugin does not generate 301s, only `meta` + JavaScript redirects.

We can verify what is going on with:

```
curl localhost:4000/a
```

Comment: instead of using the provided html i used 'layout: page' so i dont get the site to blink while redirecting

Answer (score 9):

#### This solution allows you to use true HTTP redirects via .htaccess — however, nothing involving .htaccess will work on GitHub pages because they do not use Apache.

As of May 2014 [GitHub Pages supports redirects](https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages), but according to the [jekyll-redirect-from Gem documentation](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from#usage) they are still based on [HTTP-REFRESH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) (using `<meta>` tags), which requires full a page load before redirection can occur.

I don't like the `<meta>` approach so I whipped up a solution for anyone looking to provide real HTTP 301 redirects within an .htaccess file  using Apache, which serves a pre-generated Jekyll site:

---

First, add `.htaccess` to the `include` property in `_config.yml`

```
include: [.htaccess]
```

Next, create an .htaccess file and be sure to include [YAML front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/). Those dashes are important because now Jekyll will parse the file with Liquid, Jekyll's templating language:

```
---
---
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

...
```

Make sure your posts that require redirects have two properties like so:

```
---
permalink: /my-new-path/
original: blog/my/old/path.php
---
```

Now in .htaccess, just add a loop:

```
{% for post in site.categories.post %}
  RewriteRule ^{{ post.original }} {{ post.permalink }} [R=301,L]
{% endfor %}
```

This will dynamically generate .htaccess every time you build the site, and the `include` in your config file ensures that .htaccess makes it into `_site` directory.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/my/old/path.php /my-new-path/ [R=301,L]
```

From there, it's up to you to serve `_site` using Apache. I normally clone the full Jekyll repo into a non-webroot directory, then my vhost is a symlink to the `_site` folder:

```
ln -s /path/to/my-blog/_site /var/www/vhosts/my-blog.com
```

Tada! Now Apache can serve the _site folder from your virtual root, complete with .htaccess-powered redirects that use whichever HTTP response code you desire!

You could even get super fancy and use a `redirect` property within each post's front matter to designate which redirect code to use in your .htaccess loop.

Comment: This seems great! But what if there are multiple original(previous links now hitting 404) links for a post?

Comment: The solution would involve a more complex piece of logic when you generate the `.htaccess` file. For example, you could convert the YAML so that `original` is an array instead of a string. Then you need a nested loop so that every `original` entry generates a redirect to `permalink`. Take this code as a starting point and experiment for yourself!

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work as you suggested. I've used this method for a tutorial.

Comment: since this solution doesn't work on GitHub pages, it doesn't answer the question whatsoever.  The number of irrelevant answers is infinite, so why post this at all?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg mostly to give people like you something to comment about ;)

Answer (score 6):

The best option is to avoid url changes altogether by setting the permalink format in _config.yml to match your old blog.

Beyond that, the most complete solution is generating redirect pages, but isn't necessarily worth the effort. I ended up simply making my 404 page a bit friendlier, with javascript to guess the correct new url. It doesn't do anything for search, but actual users can get to the page they were looking for and there's no legacy stuff to support in the rest of the code.

http://tqcblog.com/2012/11/14/custom-404-page-for-a-github-pages-jekyll-blog/

Answer (score 2):

Since github doesn't allow 301 redirects (which isn't surprising), you'll have to make a decision between moving to your new URL structure (and taking a search engine hit) or leaving the URLs the way they are. I suggest you go ahead and make the move. Let the search engine chips fall where they may. If someone hits one of your old links via the search engine, they'll be redirected to the new location. Over time, the search engines will pick up your changes.

Something you can do to help matters is to create a [Sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) where you only list your new pages and not the old ones. This should speed up the replacement of old URLs with the new ones. Additionally, if all your old URLs are in your '/programovani' directory, you can also use a [robots.txt file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) to tell future crawls they should ignore that directory. For example:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /programovani/
```

It will take a little while for the search engines to catch up with the changes. This isn't really a big deal. As long as the old URLs still exist and redirect actual people to the active pages, you'll be fine.

Comment: SE is not what bother me. I am getting 404 by links from other sites/forums. I've made fake pages with zero refresh time which will "redirect" user. I did test it in webmaster tools and it seems crawler is also happy with that. But i am not ;)

Comment: If you are still having problems with 404 errors, shoot me a link to one of them and I'll take a look and see if I can tell what's going on.

Comment: Right now i resolved it by the fake pages. One of the former 404 was http://www.rooland.cz/programovani/2010/04/git-co-to-je-a-co-s-tim/ . I am generating them by this http://git.io/UrlZaQ . The script is terrible, but it do what i need

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the best solution is to preserve working URLs or duplicate the pages and specify a [canonical](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) URL.

Since github pages doesn't support true redirects, I chose to set up [rerouter](https://github.com/joeyAghion/rerouter) on Heroku to return 301 (permanent) redirects from my site's old domain to the new one. I described the details here:

http://joey.aghion.com/simple-301-redirects/

Comment: Would this support more complex redirects? Such as with a single domain if I wanted to redirect links like `example.com/index.html` to `example.com` or `example.com/some-post/index.html` to `example.com/some-post/`.

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll has gone through some major updates in the past few months, so maybe this wasn't possible when this question was originally posted...

Jekyll supports a `permalink` attribute in the [YAML front-matter section](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) of your blog posts. You can specify the URL that you would like your post to have and Jekyll will use that (instead of the filename) when generating your site.

```
---
title: My special blog post
permalink: /programovani/2010/04/git-co-to-je-a-co-s-tim
---
My blog post markdown content
```

Comment: The permalink attribute just tells jekyll what to make the new generated URL, but doesn't provide anything in the way of redirects for old permalink structure that might have been in place prior.

Comment: You mean redirects of old pages on the old site? Like this is the third time the page has been moved?