# Options for changing the directory index when using GitHub Pages

Tags: .htaccess, github, webserver, web-hosting, github-pages

I'm using GitHub Pages to host a site and I'd like to rename my `index.html` file to something else (e.g. `home.html`). The issue with this is that GitHub specifically looks for and loads the default '`index.html`' as the directory index.

I understand changing the directory index is possible via server configuration files such as `.htaccess`, but GitHub Pages does not support these.

I've looked around for a bit with no luck, so I'm reaching out to see if I have any options for changing the name of the '`index.html`' file in an attempt to 'prettify' links back to my home page.

**Update**: I'd prefer to actually change the name of the directory index file GitHub is looking for versus using a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be to add a redirect from the `index.html` page to the new `home.html`.

As such, `index.thml` page remains, but almost empty.
See "[Redirect from an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411567/6309)" or "[What is the best approach for redirection of old pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19717455/6309)".

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=home.html" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Though, I'd like to see if there are options which would actually allow me to change the index vs performing a redirect. I updated my question to include this.

Comment: @willascend I suggested the redirect because I didn't know of such an option, so I'd like to see if there are too.