# Jekyll redirect link

Tags: redirect, jekyll, github-pages

I moved my site http://www.phonations.com to Jekyll/GitHub pages.

Before that, I knew how to redirect some urls on my site to external ones. How to do that now?

For example, I would like http://www.phonations.com/tmwtga to redirect to https://www.dropbox.com/s/tw1b0kvoc75c7lx/tmwtga.zip?dl=0 or some other url (using git lfs).

While the plugin ["jekyll-redirect-from"](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from) allows redirecting a path to a page, it does not seem to allow redirecting a path to another kind of resource.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it doesn't seem to do the job? What exactly have you tried? What exactly happened when you tried it? Are you using GitHub Pages, or something else? Are you encountering any errors, either in the build process or in the browser when you load the page?

Comment: The plugin makes possible to redirect a url to a page but not to another url

Comment: I'm using github pages.

Comment: I just post my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56067700/redirect-to-page-in-jekyll/56067716#56067716

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best approach for redirection of old pages in Jekyll and GitHub Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178304/what-is-the-best-approach-for-redirection-of-old-pages-in-jekyll-and-github-page)

Comment: No my question is not about redirecting content. I wanted to make available with a simple link an asset (here on dropbox). The accepted answer is cute, fine and totally in the Jekyll mindset.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That plugin does allow for redirecting to external URLs. To redirect your example URL, create a file called `tmwtga.html` and add the following front matter:

```
---
permalink: /tmwtga
redirect_to:
  - http://www.example.com
---
```

Assumes your server supports extensionless URLs (in this case GitHub Pages does). You might not need the `permalink`, but I put it in there in case you have a default set in `_config.yml`.

Source: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from#redirect-to

Comment: Thanks I missed that!

Answer (score 17):

In case

- it is OK to use the wrong HTTP response code (`200 OK` instead of `301 Moved Permanently`),
- you are hosted in GitHub pages,
- you want to rely on the build-in features, and
- you do not want to use GitHub workflows for building and pushing to `gh-pages` then

you can do following:

1. Create file `_layouts/redirect.html`:

   ```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url={{ page.redirect }}"/>
        <link rel="canonical" href="{{ page.redirect }}"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                window.location.href = "{{ page.redirect }}"
        </script>
        <title>Page Redirection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    If you are not redirected automatically, follow <a href='{{ page.redirect }}'>this link</a>.
    </body>
    </html>
   ```
2. For each page, you want to redirect from, use following content:

   ```
    ---
    redirect:   https://www.example.org
    layout:     redirect
    ---
   ```

The HTML code is an extention to the HTML code provided by a [tutorial by W3C](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-redirect-a-web-page-in-html.html).

Comment: It's worth noting that this is essentially reimplementing the plugin. See the template that jekyll-redirect-from uses here: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from/blob/master/lib/jekyll-redirect-from/redirect.html