# Redirect to page in Jekyll

Tags: redirect, jekyll

I got a problem with redirection to page in Jekyll page.

I can't `redirect_to` page what I defined by syntax:

```
---
permalink: /live/
redirect_to: https://www.youtube.com/c/PiotrKowalskiPiecioshka/live
---
```

Answer (score 0):

Any page which try use syntax `redirect_to` should be placed in `/redirects/` directory.

When I have:

```
redirects/
├── live.md
```

...redirection works!